# How is a character's soak value calculated?

Tags: combat, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

In *Star Wars: Age of Rebellion*, how do you calculate a character's soak value? Is it just brawn?

Comment: Did you read the book? What was unclear about it?

Answer (score 5):

While the base value for soak is determined by a character's brawn, they may be able to increase it other ways - such as by purchasing armor (like armored clothes) or talents (such as Endurance).